# Vuejs get token from header

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a response from server and there are auth token, max age and some other values. In Postman it looks like:
[image]

I want to set it to localStorage but have no idea how to get value in vuejs file, I tried this code:

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost:8081/login', data)
        .then(response =>{
          console.log(response.header.Authorization);
        })
```

but there is an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Authorization' of undefined
```

how it it possible to read my token from header?

Answer (score 2):

Use [headers](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#response)

```
response.headers.get('Authorization');
```

Comment: unfortunately `console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'))` returns null

Comment: @littlewombat Are you sure Authorization is coming back? Here is an example of getting a different header. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EWyBXM?editors=1010