# Vue--How do I make the <a> tag carry the request header?

Tags: vue.js

How do I make the  tag carry the request header? I use the <a> tag to download. And I need to carry a token in the request header.

Comment: You'd either need to include the token in the URL, or use JavaScript to make a request with that specific header, as far as I know.

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612255/vuejs-get-token-from-header.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `a` tag to download files or link to any document, in general, it is not possible to manipulate extra headers! Browsers will send the typical headers. To solve this problem, following are the alternative solutions.

- Your token must be query parameter in the URL so that back-end server can read it.
- Or you can use cookies to save the token and browser will ensure that cookies are sent for your request automatically. (For security, ensure that you cookie is HTTP only and rejects CORS requests)

Alternately, if you are not really after downloading the file or simply trying to show on browser, then you can use `XHR` or `fetch` where you are free to manipulate headers.

Comment: From my experience, there is no way to read or write cookies scoped to other second-level domains, regardless of HttpOnly. What are the risks if I set a jwt token in cookis with HttpOnly=false? Thanks.

Comment: @justthink The cookie becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks.